# Syntax error at or near {

Tags: linux, if-statement, awk

I have an assigment where I have to count the number of words in each .c .cc and .h file.The problem is it keeps showing the syntax error at line 8 and 10 at or near { .This is not a finished script!It may have some other problems but I only needed help with the syntax error!

```
awk  'BEGIN {FS=" ";drb=0;valt=0;}
       {if ( valt == 0 ){
         for( i=1; i<=NF; i++)
             drb++;
         valt++; 
       }
       else{
         FNR==1{ printf "File name: %s,Word count: %d\n",FILENAME, drb;drb=0;}
         for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
              drb++;}}
     END {printf "File name: %s,Word count: %d",FILENAME,drb }' `find $1 -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cc' -o -name '*.h'`
```

Comment: There is a syntax error there. Consider that you have an `if/else` statement. Within the `else` block you have an expression `FNR==1`. If that is a condition, shouldn't it also have an `if` statement? Did you mean to put it outside the `BEGIN` block?

Comment: Accepting the first answer you get is usually a bad idea. Think about it - given the many people using this site, what are the odds that the very first answer you get would actually be the best one, or even correct? After you've accepted an answer far fewer people will bother to even read your question to try to help you. Give it a few hours after you ask a question before accepting an answer. Also, edit your script to include a [mcve] as there's more wrong with your script than a syntax error and people here could help you with all of it if we know exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: if you dont have to use awk you can always use this `wc -w file file2 ...`

Comment: Oh, yes sorry I was still working on the script that's why there are more problems.I just got stuck on the syntax error and couldn't go on from that.But the problem was actually solved so that's why I accepted the answer. But it is my first question so next time I'll include the fact that it's not a finished script!

Comment: But you selected an answer that hides the problem, not fixes it. Anyway - to be clear, you are using the wrong approach and need to throw away what you have done so far. It cannot work for empty files.

Comment: You're right...could I include another if to check if the files are empty or not?And only if the file is not empty go on

Comment: Sure but it'd be using a fragile (see http://awk.info/?tip/getline) and real-time expensive `while(getline)` loop in the BEGIN section (since the main part of an awk script never gets executed for an empty file) and what's the point? If you have to add a test for an empty file then just handle it properly. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36649303/1745001) for how to deal with empty files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an action block the awk condition syntax is C-like so you need:

```
if (FNR==1) { foo }
```

instead of

```
FNR==1 { foo }
```

but more importantly it SOUNDS like all you need is:

```
awk  '
{ drb += NF }
ENDFILE { printf "File name: %s,Word count: %d",FILENAME,drb; drb=0 }
' files...
```

The above uses GNU awk for `ENDFILE`. Note that this will work even for empty files which is a BIG problem for solutions using other awks (if they rely on testing `FNR==1` instead of having a loop on `ARGV[]` in an `END` section, they will skip the file instead of printing it's name with word count zero).

The correct way to do this with non-gawk awks (assuming no duplicate file names) is:

```
awk  '
{ drb[FILENAME] += NF }
END {
    for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++) {
        fname = ARGV[i]
        printf "File name: %s,Word count: %d",fname,drb[fname]
    }
}
' files...
```

If you CAN have duplicate file names then it gets even harder to implement, something like this (untested):

```
awk  '
FNR==1 { ++cnt[FILENAME] }
{ drb[FILENAME,cnt[FILENAME]] += NF }
END {
    delete cnt
    for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++) {
        fname = ARGV[i]
        printf "File name: %s,Word count: %d",fname,drb[fname,++cnt[fname]]
    }
}
' files...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the accepted answer is correct.  Since this is a h/w problem I'll provide you a template to understand and work on it

```
awk 'FNR==1{if(s) print f,s; s=0; f=FILENAME} {s+=NF} END{print f,s}' files
```

notes: you already have NF as the loop condition just use it.
special handling is for the first file, but can be done in other ways too.

Of course what you actually need is already implemented as a command `wc`

```
wc -w files
```

will give you the results you need, pipe to `awk` for your formatting needs.

Comment: You're right, but the author is completely aware. Look at her comment: "Thank you! It worked! Yes it should have been in an if/else statement ". She was working on the script, got stuck and asked for help on this particular issue.

Comment: well, technically you fixed the syntax error...  It's a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: I insists your answer is better though. I'm glad you are able to provide even more insights to the question.

Comment: FWIW this will not print anything given an empty input file instead of printing the file name with a word count of zero.